# register process + php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, dreamweaver, registration

I am creating a registration form with php and mysql and I want to check if the required filed are empty or no but the problem is that I get only an error message if the username filed is empty without displaying the other error messages  anyone can help me with this problem??

## register.php

```
<!--<?php require_once('for members/scripts/global.php');?>--> 
<?php 
$message = "";
if(isset($_POST['username'])){
  $username = $_POST['username'];
  $fname = $_POST['fname'];
  $lname = $_POST['lname'];
  $email = $_POST['email'];
  $pass1 = $_POST['pass1'];
  $pass2 = $_POST['pass2'];
  $bdate = $_POST['birthdate'];
  $phone = $_POST['phonenumber'];
  $country = $_POST['country'];
  $local_adress = $_POST['adress'];
  @$specialization = $_POST['specialisation'];


  //error handeling
  if((!$username)||(!$fname)||(!$lname)||(!$email)||(!$pass1)||(!$pass2)||(!$bdate)||(!$phone)||(!$country)||(!$local_adress)||(!$specialization)){
  $message = "please insert all fields below";

 if($username == "")
 {
      $message = "Enter User Name";
 }
 if($fname = "")
 {
     $message = "Enter First name";
 }
 if($email = "")
 {
     $message = "Enter Email Adress";
 }
  if($pass1 = "")
 {
     $message = "Enter password";
 }
  if($pass2 = "")
 {
     $message = "rechek the password ";
 }


 } 
   else if($pass1!=$pass2){
   $message = "your password do not match!";
   }else{
   //securing the data
   $username = preg_replace("#[^0-9a-z]#i","",$username);
   $fname = preg_replace("#[^0-9a-z]#i","",$fname);
   $lname = preg_replace("#[^0-9a-z]#i","",$lname);
   $pass1 = sha1($pass1);

   $email = mysql_real_escape_string($email);
   // checking for duplicate
   $user_query = mysql_query("SELECT username FROM members WHERE username = '$username'LIMIT 1") or die("could not check the username");
   $count_username = mysql_num_rows($user_query);

    $email_query = mysql_query("SELECT email FROM members WHERE email = '$email'LIMIT 1") or die("could not check the username");
   $count_email = mysql_num_rows($email_query);

    if($count_username > 0){
     $message = " your username is alredy in use";
    }elseif($count_email > 0){
      $message = "your email is alredy in use";
    }else{
      // insert the members
      $ip_adress = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
      $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO members(username, firstname, lastname, email, password, ip_adress, sign_up_date)VALUES('$username', '$fname', '$lname', '$email', '$pass1', '$ip_adress',  now())")or die("could not insert data"); 
    $member_id = mysql_insert_id();
    mkdir("users/$member_id",0755);
    $message = "you have  now been registered";
    header("Location: home.php");
    }
   }
 }





?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Register Page</title>
<link href="style/stylesheet.css"rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
</head>

<body>
<div id="visitorHeader">
<img src="web_header copy.jpg" alt="visitor header" />
</div>
<div class="container center"> 
<p><?php print("$message")?></p>
<table width="280" border="1" align="center">
<form action="register.php" method="post">
<tr>
<td><label for="username"><span class="Fields">User Name</span> <span class="requiredField">*</span></label></td>
<td>
<input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" /><br /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><label for="firstname"><span class="Fields">First Name</span> <span class="requiredField">*</span></label></td>
<td>
<input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="Firstname" /><br /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><label for="lasttname" class="Fields">Last Name</label></td>
<td>    
<input type="text" name="lname" placeholder="Lastname" /><br /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><label for="birthdate" class="Fields">Birth Date</label></td>
<td>
<input type="date" name="birthdate" value= "YYYY_MM_DD"  onfocus="if (this.value == 'YYYY_MM_DD') {this.value = '';}" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'YYYY_MM_DD';}" /><br /></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td class="Fields"><label for="phonenumber">Phone Number</label>
 <td>
 <input type="tel" name="phonenumber" value="000-0-000 000" onfocus="if (this.value == '000-0-000 000') {this.value = '';}" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = '000-0-000 000';}" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="Fields"><label for="country">Country</label></td>
<td> 
<select name="country" id="country"><option selected=>please choose coutry<option>lebanon<option>Us<option>europe 
    </select></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="Fields"><label for="adress">Local Adress <span class="requiredField">*</span></label></td>
<td>
<input type="text" name="adress" placeholder="adress" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="Fields"><label for="specialisation">Specialisation <span class="requiredField">*</span></label></td>
<td>
<select name="specialisation" id="specialisation">
    </select></td>
    </tr>

<tr>
<td class="Fields"><label for="email">Email Adress<span class="requiredField">*</span></label></td>
<td>
<input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email Adress" /><br /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="Fields"><label for="password">Password<span class="requiredField">*</span></label></td>
<td>
<input type="password" name="pass1" placeholder="Password" /><br /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="Fields"><label for="password2">Re_Password<span class="requiredField">*</span></label></td>
<td>
<input type="password" name="pass2" placeholder="Validate Password" /><br /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<input type="submit" value="Register"/>
</td>

</tr>
</form>
</table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One reason you're only getting one error message instead of all of them is because you're overwriting the `$message` variable each time you encounter a new error. For this, append the string to the error message instead:

```
if ($username == "") {
    $message = $message . "Enter User Name<br/>";
}
```

As for why the username is the only one creating an error message, it is because you are using a single `=` on the other if statements which, if I remember correctly, returns the value assigned, and in this case it's an empty string, which evaluates to false. You need to do:

```
 if($fname == "")
 {
     $message = $message . "Enter First name<br/>";
 }
 if($email == "")
 {
     $message = $message . "Enter Email Adress<br/>";
 }
  if($pass1 == "")
 {
     $message = $message . "Enter password<br/>";
 }
  if($pass2 == "")
 {
     $message = $message . "rechek the password <br/>";
 }
```

**edit** Changed `$message .= "..."` to `$message = $message . "..."` so it's more clear that we're appending to the string, and added `<br/>` tags to the messages since `$message` is being printed in the html.

Comment: this solution did not work still give the same result anw thank you

Comment: Hmm... What do you get if you print out the variables that aren't working?

Comment: you mean when i print he $message?? i get nothing

Comment: @devleb I meant $fname, $email, $pass1, $pass2. Your question says you only get the error message when $username is empty. I interpreted that as there is actually something being printed out by $message. Is there any real error messages that you get when you run this?

Comment: nooooo the error message display is **please insert all fields below**. if i do not fil the username field the error msg is **enter username**

Comment: That's exactly what I thought was happening and exactly what should have been fixed by my answer... The `.` operator adds a string to another string. So if $message is "please insert all fields below" and you do `$message .= "Enter First name";` $message should now be "please insert all fields belowEnter First name". I'll edit my answer to make it more clear what's happening. But it's strange that it's not working for you. I tested it myself with success...

Comment: thank you  jonhopkins your solution is perfect thank you but i have a silly question how to make these error msg colored red ??

Comment: There are several ways. Two of the quicker options are either change your `<p>` tag in the html to `<p style="color: red">` or in each error message do `$message = $message . '<span style="color: red">error message</span><br/>';` I personally like the second one because it allows you to pick a different color for each message if you want.

Comment: thank you for your help, i think the first one will do the job for me

Comment: **jonhopkins** i have a question but out of this scope is about sessions and the login and logout process can you help me ??   i know i ask many questions but you are the first person that truly help me  hope that i am not bothering you.

Comment: @devleb hey, sorry I didn't reply last night. Got kinda busy. Considering that your question is a completely different topic, and will probably be difficult to ask/solve through comments, I would recommend posting a new question on StackOverflow and I will help you from there.

Comment: this is the link for the new question if you can help me [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15274352/php-mysql-session-problems]